# Do I need to connect AudioListener to AudioDestinationNode?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Im working on spatial audio for a project. Im trying to figure out the correct way to use AudioListener and AudioDestinationNode. I don't have my dev machine available, so I can't test and brute-force to find out, so what is the proper way to connect all this?

AudioListener says it's not an Audio node. And I can't find the documentation for this specific issue

Comment: Quite unclear what your question is. You set the listeners for the whole context, not just for a particular destination.

Comment: Sorry, if there's a better way to word it please let me know. But I'm learning web audio API, and I'm trying to understand where they fit in the pipeline. Like how do I get a connection from a source node, through gain node, then to where? Does it go to the listener, the destination, both?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't take any connections. So do I route all the connections into the destination node?

Comment: The `listener` is only(?) used by [PannerNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode).

Comment: Ahh ok. So if I understand, `listener` is not attached to the audio graph, but referenced by `PannerNode`s which are attached to the graph?